# Average with the Reduce Method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

recently I tried to calculate  **Average with the Reduce Method In JavaScript​** here is may code

```
var arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

var result = arr.reduce(function (start, end, index, array){
  var total =start + end;
  var array_length = array.length;
  return total/array_length;
});
console.log(result);
```

my result is 57.875 but it's wrong, where is my problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: You are dividing each intermediate step by the length. That's not how you get the average. You sum all the values first and then divide.

Comment: Check out [what the arguments for reduce are](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Given your variable names, it seems you're mistaken about what the first and the second parameters are.

Comment: @deceze alternatively, divide each member by length and then sum. But then again, that will probably lead to problems with fractions.

Comment: Interesting article if you have an array of objectif : https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2019/five-ways-to-average-with-js-reduce/

Answer (score 34):

You could add all values, who are divided by the length to get the average.

```js
var array = [129, 139, 155, 176],
    average = array.reduce(function (avg, value, _, { length }) {
        return avg + value / length;
    }, 0);

console.log(average);
```

Or take the sum of all values and divide by the length of the array. The result is the same.

```js
var array = [129, 139, 155, 176],
    average = array.reduce(function (sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0) / array.length;

console.log(average);
```

Comment: `{ length }` thats new to me.

Comment: @null, it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) by taking an object and getting a property.

Comment: The first code is to avoid as you sum approximations due to the division of each value by the length of the array. Plus second code performs better.

Comment: The first one is a really cool, compact way to do this. This is especially helpful when I'm chaining lots of array functions like map, filter, etc, then I can just use this reduce to find the avg without the need to store it as a separate variable first for accessing length. If very high precision is not your concern, then this is perfect!

Answer (score 5):

You have repeated reduce on each item of the array. What the other answers are doing they havent reduced the array into the average result, instead they did sum and then reduced and you needed 2 steps to do that.

The good functional programmers, we wanna think as one "**pure, one shot**" way to transform our input data into the thing we really want. This should leave almost a little bit of code smell.

The better way to do that is you can use couple of supported arguments of the reduce function.

See the code and hope that helps with your answer. Happy coding :)

```js
     var arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];
    
    function reducer(acc, value, index, array) {
    
      var calculatedValue = acc + value;
    
      if (index === array.length - 1) {
        return calculatedValue / array.length;
      }
    
      return calculatedValue;
    }
    
    var result = arr.reduce(reducer, 0);
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: That is a great solution because it works even with an empty array (array.length = 0)

Answer (score 4):

What you call `start` in your code is in fact what is returned from the previous iteration. At each step, you add the current element of the array (you called it `end`) to what was returned at the previous iteration (`start`) and divide the sum by the length of the array. This is indeed not the average.

Here is how you can compute the average using a reducer:

```js
const arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

// sum all the elements of the array
const sum = arr.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue){
  return accumulator + currentValue;
}, 0);

const average = sum / arr.length;

console.log(average);
```

Comment: Which can be simplified to `arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / arr.length`.

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts It does not work, but works when I add the starting total of 0, so ```arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length``` works.

Comment: @musicformellons true.

Comment: @musicformellons Thanks for the feedback I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use array length, and can be potentially used for calculating the average for a stream of numbers:

```js
const average = (numbersArray) =>
  numbersArray.reduce(
    (result, currentValue) => ({
      average: result.average + (currentValue - result.average) / result.count,
      count: result.count + 1,
    }),
    { average: 0, count: 1 }
  ).average;

console.log(average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the reduce() method you can get the average of your array. The **array** argument gives you the array to traverse and using that you can get the length to divide it by the sum of your array. The **initialValue** should be set to 0.

In addition, this works great if you need to chain methods (e.g., map() and filter()) as your array length may be different before filtering.

reduce((**previousValue**, **currentValue**, currentIndex, **array**) => { ... }, **initialValue**)

```
var arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

var result = arr.reduce(
  (start, end, index, array) => start + end / array.length,
  0
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically asked for ES6:

```js
let arr = [129, 139, 155, 176]
let avg = arr.reduce((a,b) => a+b) / arr.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding an ES6+ arrow function answer here:

```js
const arr = [22,295,176,440,37,105,10,1100,86,52] // Arr values ex.

const calcAverage = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((first, next) => first + next) / arr.length
}

// Or even cleaner w/o return/brackets
const calcAverage = (arr) => arr.reduce((first, next) => first + next) / arr.length

const avg = calcAverage(arr)
// Do whatever with averge
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple and elegant solution to find both moving average and average using map

```
const movingAverage = function (arr) {
    let avg = arr[0]
    return arr.map(current => (avg + current) / 2);
}

const average = function (arr) {
    let avg = arr[0]
    return arr.map(current => (avg + current) / 2)[arr.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide only the value by `arr.length` (except for the first round)

Answer (score -1):

The following code helps see what's happening:

```
var arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

var result = arr.reduce(function (start, end, index, array){
  
  var total =start + end;
  var array_length = array.length;
  var running_average = total / array_length;

  console.log(`At index ${index}`);
  console.log(`start:${start} end:${end} total:${total}`);
  console.log(`Running average: ${running_average}`);

  return running_average;
});

console.log(result);
```

Change your code as follows to fix the issue:

```
var arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

result = arr.reduce(function(start, end, index, array){
  
  let total = start + end;
  let array_length = array.length;

  // console.log(`At index ${index}`);
  // console.log(`start:${start} end:${end} total:${total}`);
  
  if(index === array_length - 1){
    return total / array_length;
  }
  else{
    return total;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Whatever you return from a previous iteration becomes 'start' (or first) argument to the next iteration function call.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [129, 139, 155, 176];

const calcAverage = (scores) =>
  scores.reduce(
    (accu, ele, i, arrs) =>
      i + 1 === arrs.length ? (accu + ele) / (i + 1) : accu + ele,
    0
  );
console.log(calcAverage(arr));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to improve on existing answers. When answering an already answered question, please either demonstrate improvement over existing answers, or offer a fresh angle

Answer (score -1):

We can use the reduce() property in JS array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const average = (scores) => scores.reduce((sum, elem) => sum + elem, 0) / scores.length)
console.log(average(arr)) // 10
```

More details can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

Comment: This calculates sum and not avergae. Output should have been 2.5 instead of 10